# request permission window force application to stop

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-permissions

I need to request a permission manually for API level 23 and where the dialog window appears and the application goes into background.

Here is my code:

```
  @Override
    public void onDialogDone(int dialog, boolean result) {
        DialogFragment newFragment;

        switch (dialog) {
            case EULA_DIALOG:
                if (result) {

                    boolean numberExists = _appRegistration.checkPhoneNumber();
                    if (!numberExists) {
                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                                new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE},
                                MY_PERMISSIONS_PHONE_STATE_READ);
                        return;
                    } else {
                        //do some work
                    }
                } else {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(...);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();


                 }


                       break;.... 
  }
}
```

Also, in the MainActivity I have overridden the following method:

```
@Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        switch (requestCode) {
            case MY_PERMISSIONS_PHONE_STATE_READ: {    
                if (grantResults.length > 0
                        && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                   // do some work
                } else {

                    // do some work
                }

                return;
            }

        }
```

But if I click "allow" or "deny", this method is not called, because application is in background mode... I logged `onPause` and `onStop` methods and both of them are called after the permission window is shown.

[image]

Comment: Does it force stop your app on deny?

Comment: doesn't matter , when the dialog is shown , application is going in background. it doesn't wait for the answer

Comment: I think this is problamatic  Intent intent = new Intent(...);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
,not sure about your if(result) but else part is problamatic

Comment: while debug 'requestPermissions' is called , is it possible to run if and else block together? :d

Comment: How can it possible to run if and else both? never possible that if and else both will run togather

Comment: give your activity code please where you are calling this permission

Comment: ok so instead of return; statement in your if condition put break :P for your :d;

Comment: yeah, I know :d. permission dialog is show, so else block is not run. application should still in foreground. i will update the question

Comment: @AjayPandya is doesn't make seance , I have already tried it

Comment: What was your solution? I got the same issue :(

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There was MainActivity problem, in manifest file it was configured as:

> android:noHistory="true"

I just removed this property and application started working as it was expected.

Comment: +1 This fixed my issue.  Seems silly that this would break it and there isn't another way to request permissions without background'ing the app.  I have a Launch screen that asks for location, but I don't want them getting back to the launch screen.  So instead of declaratively, I have to do it programmatically.  WHY Google?!

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
      if (!numberExists) {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(),
                            new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE},
                            MY_PERMISSIONS_PHONE_STATE_READ);
                    return;
```

This way you are starting the request from your activity and the callbacks will be received.

Comment: I changed it, Try now. If it doesnt work will look into it further.

Comment: what is difference than the question

Comment: getActivity() doesn't exists in current context

Comment: coz you are in Activity not in Fragment